# Android BoardcastReceiver waiti for network connection to execute function

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I set a repeated AlarmManager which will send the pendingIntent on certain time to call the BoardcastReceiver for perform update content of my apps. What my problem is how do i wait for the network connection is establish, then execute the update module?

**For example, the AlarmManager will trigger BoardcastReceiver on every Saturday 1pm to perform update, but now if there has no network connection it will miss the update.**

I had try this in my BoardcastReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(final Context context,Intent intent)
{
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    while(!isConnected(context))
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        Log.e("MyAPP","Sleep");
                    }
                    Updater updater = new Updater(context);
                    updater.execute();
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        };
    thread.start();
}
```

isConnected() work well, but when i establish the connection, updater doesnt execute. Any common or good idea to perform a auto-update? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

let your BroadcastReceiver start a Service